# jquery confusing code

Tags: javascript, jquery, cart

I am learning Jquery and Javascript from web examples. I have a good working knowledge but some code still trips me up. The following code is used for a shopping cart to hide the check out button and replace with a div displaying a message about minimum cart requirements. There is a part of the code throwing me off though.

```
function getCollectionCount() {
  var totalCollectionCount = 0;    
  var collection = $('td[alt*="Collection"]');
  for (var i = 0; i < collection.length; i++) {
    var curVal = $(collection[i]).find("select").val();
    if (curVal != undefined){
      totalCollectionCount += parseInt(curVal);
    }
  }
```

What does this part mean?

```
var collection = $('td[alt*="Collection"]');
```

Comment: Perhaps the jquery documentation would have been a good place to look: http://api.jquery.com/attribute-contains-selector/

Comment: Here's a useful site: the [SelectOracle](http://tux.theopalgroup.com/cgi-bin/css3explainer/selectoracle.py). That site has a very confusing layout, but the idea is that you clear out the "Direct Input" textarea, type in a CSS selector, and then click the "Explain This" button sort-of buried a little ways down the page.

Answer (score 7):

`td[alt*="Collection"]` selects all `<td>` elements whose `alt` attribute contains `Collection`, such as:

```
<td alt="Collection"></td>
<td alt="CollectionFoo"></td>
<td alt="BarCollection12324343"></td>
```

but not

```
<td></td>
<td alt=""></td>
<td alt="Foo"></td>
```

---

Side note: this is a pretty basic question that could easily be answered by read the [jQuery selectors API documentation](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/):

- [element selector](http://api.jquery.com/element-selector/)
- [attribute-contains selector](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-contains-selector/)

Please do try to research before you ask!

Comment: I'll note that, stylistically, using the "alt" attribute value as something to drive JavaScript logic is a little flaky or "code-smelly".  Also, are you sure that "*=" means "starts with" and not just "contains"?  Personally I can never remember stuff like that.

Comment: Thank you I never would have thought of that, but it does make sense. So I can select any specific element based on it's attribute? Such as `div[alt*="test1"]` will select all `<div>` elements with the attribute of `test1`

Comment: @Pointy so what do you recommend instead of using the `alt` attribute?

Comment: You are right it after looking at your responses I see it is a very basic question, and I did call myself trying to figure it out on my own, it was a small part of a much larger project and I just got stumped on this one part. I apologize if the question was annoyingly simple, but thank you for everyone's response.

Comment: Well the "alt" attribute will contain user-directed messaging describing the image in case it cannot be shown for some reason. That messaging may be translated into another language, or may change for stylistic reasons, so using the "alt" value from code is a "fragile" construct.  There are other attributes that can and should be used to control JavaScript - the "class", for one, and the HTML5 "data-whatever" family of attributes.

Answer (score 1):

This is a jQuery attribute selector clause.  It's selecting any `td` element which has an atrtibute named `alt` whose string contains the value `Collection`.

Contains Selector: http://api.jquery.com/attribute-contains-selector/

jQuery has a number of useful attribute selectors.  Here is the main reference page for them.  Very much worth the read if you're just getting started with jQuery

- http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/attribute-selectors/

Answer (score 1):

That code returns every td element whose "alt" attribute contains "Collection".

http://api.jquery.com/attribute-contains-selector/

jQuery is full of these funky shortcuts that take forever to learn, so I always keep a copy of [jQuery in action](http://www.manning.com/bibeault/) on my desk at all times :)

Answer (score 1):

This code can be rewritten more simply and briefly like this:

```
function getCollectionCount() {
    var totalCollectionCount = 0;    
    $('td[alt*="Collection"] select').each(function() {
        var val = this.value || "0";
        totalCollectionCount += parseInt(val, 10);
    });
    return(totalCollectionCount);
}
```

And, this is how it works:

1. Initialize totalCollectionCount to 0
2. Find all td elements that have the string "Collection" in the alt attribute and then find select elements within that td
3. Iterate over all elements found that match the above condition
4. Initialize a local variable with either the value of the select object or "0" if there is no value or it's empty
5. Turn that value into a number (must pass the radix to parseInt so it won't guess) and add it to the sub-total so far.
6. return the total we found.